# How to work successfully my ContainerAwareCommand using Job class?

Tags: symfony

Here is my ContainerAwareCommand class,

```
class myCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
   protected function configure()
   {
      $this
        ->setName('entity:new')
        ->setDescription('my command.')
        ->addArgument(
           'entity',
           InputArgument::REQUIRED,
           'entity ID'
        )
     ;
  }

  protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

and below code is part of function of other class,

```
$job = New Job();
$job->setCommand('entity:new '.$entity->getId());

$this->em->persist($job);
$this->em->flush();
```

I expected to run a execute function of myCommand class after '$this->em->flush();' but I think it is not work.

Please tell me the reason in this situation or how to debug easily for me.
I am symfony2 beginner.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code I assume that you use the [JmsJobQueueBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSJobQueueBundle). The code you are showing is only responsible to schedule a job in the queue. For the queued jobs to be executed, you must either run the `jms-job-queue:run` command manually or make sure that it [is executed in the background](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSJobQueueBundle/master/installation#setting-up-supervisord).

For the next time, please remember to provide more information about what other libraries you use so that people who do not that libraries will be able to help you too.